# Write a loop for penalized models

Tags: r

I'm working in R with the package glmnet for a subject at University. I'm starting to use R and i need help for some problems:

I need to do an exercise where i train and test 500 times, some models (OLS, Ridge and LASSO). After that i need to storage the MSE for each one of the 500 iterations. 
In the training step i have to use 5-fold cross-validation.

So i'm having problems with this because i can't figure out how to write the right code.

I need to know how to configurate cv.glmnet in a way i can use 5-fold cv, and how to write the loop to make the 500 iterations and storage the MSE from each one.

Thank you very much and sorry for my english!

```
#Generación de muestra de entrenamiento
ne <- 100
pe <- 100
listx<-list()
for(listx in 1:500) {
  xtrain <- matrix (rnorm(ne*pe), ne, pe)
ytrain <- apply(xtrain[,1:pe], 1, sum) + rnorm(ne)

olsreg <- lm(ytrain~xtrain)

ridgereg <-cv.glmnet(xtrain, ytrain, type.measure = "mse", alpha=0, family="gaussian")

ridgeregpr <- predict(ridgereg, s=ridgereg$lambda.min, newx=xtest)

mseridge <-mean((ytest-ridgeregpr)^2)

lassoreg <-cv.glmnet(xtrain, ytrain, type.measure = "mse", alpha=1, family="gaussian")

lassoregpr <- predict(lassoreg, s=lassoreg$lambda.min, newx=xtest)

mselasso <-mean((ytest-lassoregpr)^2)
}

results <- data.frame()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run your code and i found solution.

#### First

In your code there is no `xtest` and `ytest`.

So i made it randomly

#### Second

`listx` must be the results that stored your results, not iteration!!

I changed `listx` in `for` statement to `iter`

#### Third

I assigned results to `listx` list.
After the iteration, i used `rbindlist` to make it `data.frame` class. 
In my code i iterate it `10` times not `500` just for my convenience!!

```
library(glmnet)
library(data.table)
#Generación de muestra de entrenamiento
ne <- 100
pe <- 100
listx<-list()

for(iter in 1:10) {
  xtrain <- matrix (rnorm(ne*pe), ne, pe)
  ytrain <- apply(xtrain[,1:pe], 1, sum) + rnorm(ne)

  xtest <- matrix (rnorm((ne-50)*(pe)), ne-50)
  ytest <- apply(xtest[,1:(pe-50)], 1, sum) + rnorm(ne-50)


  olsreg <- lm(ytrain~xtrain)

  ridgereg <-cv.glmnet(xtrain, ytrain, type.measure = "mse", alpha=0, family="gaussian")

  ridgeregpr <- predict(ridgereg, s=ridgereg$lambda.min, newx=xtest)

  mseridge <-mean((ytest-ridgeregpr)^2)

  lassoreg <-cv.glmnet(xtrain, ytrain, type.measure = "mse", alpha=1, family="gaussian")

  lassoregpr <- predict(lassoreg, s=lassoreg$lambda.min, newx=xtest)

  mselasso <-mean((ytest-lassoregpr)^2)

  listx[[iter]] = data.frame(mseridge = mseridge,
                           mselasso = mselasso)

}
results <- rbindlist(listx)
```

Results are shown below

```
> results
    mseridge mselasso
 1: 36.36702 42.04854
 2: 44.73392 81.36519
 3: 40.37621 75.39565
 4: 42.75282 61.04850
 5: 42.30007 55.44008
 6: 55.58605 76.35885
 7: 38.62277 36.18105
 8: 36.77701 69.17898
 9: 56.83311 75.61917
10: 33.56595 66.23441
```